# Swift - change variable in another view controller, without knowing the class name?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I have a function in viewController1, that changes a variable in whichever view controller the function is called from (in this case viewController2)

What I've been attempting -

declaring the function in viewController1:

```
func changeVariable(controller: UIViewController) {
    controller.variable = "Hello"
}
```

calling the function from viewController2:

```
changeVariable(self)
```

However, this gives me an error when declaring the function, telling me that UIViewController has no member named 'variable'.

If I then change the function to:

```
func changeVariable() {
    viewController2.variable = "Hello"
}
```

It works. But, I don't know which view controller is calling the function beforehand (it could be viewController3, for example), so I can't explicitly state that in the function.

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what protocols are for: defining a common language between classes when you don't want to share their exact name.

You could define a `CommonVariable` protocol that describes a `variable` string:

```
protocol CommonVariable: class {
    var variable: String { get set }
}
```

Then edit your `ViewController2` definition to conform to this protocol:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, CommonVariable {
    var variable = ""
}
```

And edit your `ViewController1` method to accept a `CommonVariable` as the parameter:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    func changeVariable(controller: CommonVariable) {
        controller.variable = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Now this method knows nothing about `controller` except that it's a class with a string called `variable`.

As a result, you will be able to call the method from `ViewController2` without knowing the class name:

```
func someFunc() {
    viewController1.changeVariable(controller: self)
}
```

---

As a side note, `CommonVariable`, `variable`, `ViewController1`, and `ViewController2` are all bad names. Not sure if you're actually using these names, but you should aim for something more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented a variant of what you described and it works perfectly. Also, those variables were just for demonstrative purposes.